# dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZN11SkJpegCodec6IsJpegEPKvj" referenced by libmyskia.so

Tags: google-chrome, cmake, android-ndk, java-native-interface, skia

I am trying to build skia for android using the master branch. But I got the following error:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZN11SkJpegCodec6IsJpegEPKvj" referenced by ".../libmyskia.so"...
>           at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1016)

Some details:

1) The command to build skia:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "generating ninja build files..."

bin/gn gen out/x86 --args='ndk="/Users/rowandjj/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/" target_cpu="x86" ndk_api=21 target_os="android" is_official_build=false is_component_build=true is_debug=false skia_use_system_expat=false skia_use_system_freetype2=false skia_use_system_libpng=false skia_use_icu=false skia_use_libjpeg_turbo=false skia_use_libwebp=false skia_use_piex=false'
echo "ninja compiling and linking..."
/usr/local/bin/ninja -C out/x86
echo "job done!"
```

2) The CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
set(distribution_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/include/android)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/include/atlastext)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/include/c)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/include/codec)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/include/config)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/include/core)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/include/effects)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/include/encode)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/include/gpu)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/include/pathops)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/include/ports)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/include/private)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/include/svg)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/include/utils)

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        myskia

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        IMPORTED )


set_target_properties(
        myskia
        PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${distribution_DIR}/${ANDROID_ABI}/libmyskia.so
)

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        native-lib

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp)

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
        log-lib

        # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
        # you want CMake to locate.
        log)

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        native-lib

        myskia

        # Links the target library to the log library
        # included in the NDK.
        ${log-lib})
```

3) my NDK version: 18.1.5063045

4) gradle version: 4.6 / gradle plugin version: 3.2.1

5) build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.foo.android.helloskia"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments "-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-26"
                cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
            }
        }

        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a',"x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {

        main {
            jniLibs.srcDir "./libs"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: same problems here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/skia-discuss/WMhbVzPJmCM/b4Ca9tkHAQAJ

Comment: anyone can help me out....

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/skia-discuss/ne_Kw1dY8y0

Comment: What do readelf/nm say? Does that symbol exist in the library?

Comment: @DanAlbert hi, thanks for your reply. nm say that _ZN* symbol is not defined. 


>  nm -u libskia.so | grep _ZN11SkJpegCodec6IsJpegEPKvj
 
>  U _ZN11SkJpegCodec6IsJpegEPKvj

Comment: Ah, solved finally! set skia_use_libjpeg_turbo argument to true...

Comment: Feel free to leave an answer to your own question and mark it as correct. It's helpful for other people that might later land here looking for an answer.